# Generate Shorten classnames

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, css-selectors

How to shorten class names in html and in css files

I have this class name

```
.profile-author-name-upper
```

And want to change this like this

```
.p-a-n-u
```

or

```
.panu
```

I'm usinig js task runner GruntJS

Comment: If you are using it to save some bytes on bandwidth - this is definitely not worth it since it requires very complicated workflow. You need to filter out not only css and html but also JS since it also can `$('.profile-author-name-upper').hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is uglification 
This is just part from [tutorial](http://grunt-tasks.com/grunt-contrib-uglify/) I copied online from **grunt-contrib-uglify** grunt plugin

Simple Configuration

```
npm install grunt grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

This will install grunt as well uglifyjs in your node_modules devDependencies as well as update package.json

Inside your Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
      uglify: {
        my_target: {
          files: {
            'dest/minified.js': ['src/jquery.js', 'src/angular.js']
          }
        }
      }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); // load the given tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']); // Default grunt tasks maps to grunt
  };
```

From the command line:

*$ grunt
  Running "uglify:my_target" (uglify) task

> > 1 file created.
> >       Done, without errors*

Comment: Uglify is for javascript, the guy wants to shorten his html/css class selectors.

Comment: Yeah, i want for html/css class selectors.